# Разделение строки Python

Tags: python, discord.py

Нужно разделить содержимое строки
Будет вводиться команда пользователем по шаблону:

```
$Фамилия Имя Отчество 1Группа1-18
```

Группа начинается на цифру и заканчивается ей же. Нужно содержимое `message.content` распределить на 2 переменные: new_nick и group. Так же если введено не по шаблону вылезала ошибка.

```py
if message.content.startswith('$'):
new_nick = ""
fio = 0
group = " "
content = message.content[1:]
for i in content:
    if fio == 3:
        group += i
    else:
        if i.isalpha():
            new_nick += str(i)
        if i == " ":
            new_nick += " "
            fio +=1
```

Comment: Нужно содержимое message.content распределить на 2 переменные: new_nick и group.

Comment: Регулярное выражение проще всего использовать по идее. Хотя если ФИО всегда точно ровно три слова, то можно и по пробелам разбить попробовать. А, ну если группа всегда без пробелов, то тоже пробелами можно обойтись через `split` и срезы.

Comment: Сам сделал, но как можно улучшить?

Comment: `new_nick, group = message.content[1:].rsplit(" ",1)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Рекомендую использовать встроенный модуль `re`

```
import re

message = "$Фамилия Имя Отчество 518"

name_pattern    = "[а-яА-Я]+ [а-яА-Я]+ [а-яА-Я]+"
group_pattern   = "\d+"
message_pattern = "\$" + name_pattern + " " + group_pattern

if (re.match(message_pattern, message)):
    name  = re.search(name_pattern,  message).group(0)
    group = re.search(group_pattern, message).group(0)
    print("Name:  " + name)
    print("Group: " + group)
else:
    raise ValueError("Incorrect message format")
```

*Подробнее: https://tproger.ru/translations/regular-expression-python/*

---

Также возможен менее универсальный но простой вариант

```
message = "$Фамилия Имя Отчество 518"

if (message.startswith("$")):
    message = message[1:]
    content = message.split(" ")
    name  = " ".join(content[:3])
    group = " ".join(content[3:])
    print("Name:  " + name)
    print("Group: " + group)
else:
    raise ValueError("Incorrect message format")
```

Comment: Спасибо, но он в группу забирает только цифры, там между цифр идут буквы

Comment: @DmitryBelskii исправьте регулярку для `group_pattern` на что-то подобное: [0-9А-Яа-я]{3,}-\d+. То есть включены все буквы и цифры, знак `-` после и целое число в конце

Comment: `group_pattern = "\d[а-яА-Я]+\d+-\d+"`

Comment: Поставьте моему ответу ещё и стрелочку вверх